# NSCFString leaking when handling key events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, memory-leaks, appkit

I am trying to capture key presses with this code. My problem is that Instruments throws a message about a leak.

I am working without Garbage Collection.

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if ([theEvent keyCode]==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Break");
    }
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Message thrown by Instruments:

```
Leaked Object  #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
NSCFString,    0x10067e540 32 Bytes    AppKit  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
```

Comment: That is all of the code?  Turn on GC and see if it still leaks.

Comment: There is no leak in the code you are showing here; there isn't even an NSString (the @"Break" is constant and not leaking).

Comment: That's not the relevant code producing the leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at 
[Why is NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel showing memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987150/why-is-nsopenpanel-nssavepanel-showing-memory-leak/6990304#6990304)
and 
[NSTextField leaking when handling key events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115007/nstextfield-leaking-when-handling-key-events)

Your problem shows the same symptoms and it may also be a "False Positive".

Credit for this answer should go to [Rob Keniger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50122/rob-keniger) he has pointed me in the right direction.