# OSX NSOpenPanel memory issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have called following code on button click.

```
NSOpenPanel *aPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
```

above line freeze whole application and memory increase from 10 mb to 2gb and goes increasing. I have added panel setting code

```
NSOpenPanel *aPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[aPanel setMessage: @"Choose folders";
[aPanel setPrompt:@"Select";
[aPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[aPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[aPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[aPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
```

I have already go through
    [NSOpenPanel related memory questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009317/nsopenpanel-related-memory-questions)
[Why is NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel showing memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987150/why-is-nsopenpanel-nssavepanel-showing-memory-leak/6990304)

Comment: Can you step over `NSOpenPanel *aPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];`?

Comment: no application does not respond after this line.

Comment: Do you call this on main thread? Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: yes i called this on main thread

Comment: Obvious next steps: break the application and see what's on the stack and where the code is. Run it in instruments and find out what memory is being allocated and by what code.