# Activity monitor: com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService does not terminate

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel, xpc

I have a SwiftUI/AppKit app (for compatibility with macos 10.15).
I have successfully implemented an open and a save file method using `NSOpenPanel` and `NSSavePanel`.

I noticed in macOS' activity monitor, that the 2 processes `com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService ...`and `QuickLookUIService (com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService ...` open as soon as my methods are called, but they never terminate. After open/save is finished, they use only minimal CPU and little memory (19 & 3 MB).

I don't see problems so far, but I wonder why those helper processes don't terminate/deallocate.

Here's my code in my `AppDelegate`:

```
@IBAction func openDocument(_ sender: Any?) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.prompt = "Import"
    openPanel.title = "Choose a .plist file"
    openPanel.titleVisibility = .visible
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["plist"] // TODO: deprecated in macOS 12
    openPanel.setFrameAutosaveName("Open Panel")
    let result = openPanel.runModal()
    if result == .OK {
        if let fileUrl = openPanel.url {
            let path = fileUrl.path
            print("selected file to open: '\(path)'")
            loadArray(from: fileUrl)
        }
    } else if result == .cancel {
        print("Open document (Import Actions) was cancelled")
    }
}
```

Is this behaviour of the XPC processes normal, or a bug/leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found this answer:
[Why is NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel showing memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990304/16157878)

It says that `NSOpenPanel`/`NSSavePanel` are **singletons** where "the first time you call [them], an instance of `NSOpenPanel` is created and not released. **This is not a leak, it's an optimisation**."